# Which of the following implementations is faster?

Tags: c++, matrix, macros, functional-programming

What I'm trying to do is fill the values of a specific matrix using unknown variables.

Here's the first implementation:

```
#define PHI(I,J,K) phi[xlength*ylength*(I)+xlength*(J)+(K)] //Macro that calls function
```

Where phi is a 1D matrix of dimensions xlength*ylength*tlength

or

```
phi= new double[xlength*ylength*tlength]; //code for phi
```

The other option is to define a function like

```
void PHI(double *&phi, int &I, int &J, int &K, double &value) //declare function
{
   phi[xlength*ylength*I+xlength*J+K]=value; //return specific value of phi
}
```

I would use the macro or function in something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<tlength;i++) //just making a loop here
{
  for (int j=0;j<ylength;j++)
  {
    PHI(i,j,1)= stuff here //The macro or the function would go here
  }
}
```

So what I'm doing is either using a macro to point to a specific cell of the matrix phi[] or I'm using a function to fill a specific value of the matrix phi[].

Which is faster?

Comment: Find it out by benchmarking your program. Stack Overflow members might be smart, but their brains certainly don't have the computational capabilities of a modern CPU.

Comment: Oh okay. Ha ha! I was just checking whether passing all those things to a function or simply using a macro would be faster. If it's unknown, I guess I could just test it.

Comment: @H2CO3 but I can use macros that way, right? It's okay to have a variable from a for loop inside a macro, right?

Comment: OK in what sense? If it compiles, then it's syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely no difference at all. The compiler will inline the function just as much as it inlines the macro. Since macros are much harder to use in a debugger, use a function.

And as I always say in case of "which performs better", you should always benchmark the different options, since differences in compilers can make some small difference in some cases (and in other cases make a big difference). Asking on SO or some other internet site will only tell you what other people think, not what actually happens in your real case.